# React- validate if there is a user in the database

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using useEffect lists the users that exist in the database, but how can I create a condition that validates that the user entering the textfield exists or does not exist?

I save the API values ​​in the user state, but even if I type a valid user in the textfield it always appears that it does not exist

```
const[user, setUser]=useState({})

    useEffect(()=>{
        const getUsers = async()=>{
          const response = await axios.get('/api/ListUser')
          setUser(response.data);
        }
        getUsers();
      },[])

const error = user;

          <TextField
              name="user"
              label="User"
              value={list.name}
              onChange={onchange}
              variant="outlined"
              helperText={error ? "Exists ":"does not exist"}
              error={error}
              />
```

Comment: Where does `error` get set? Can you share  [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code? i.e. can you edit your question to include the necessary component code to see how you are attempting to process your data and compute any error?

Comment: @DrewReese you're right don't explain that part i already corrected my question and add more code snippet

Comment: So when you are processing your response and just set the `user` state object how do you differentiate success from error? Your API endpoint should return an error. Typically you'd use a try/catch to process your async API requests, setting some error state in the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to change the Functional component to the Class component?

If you are a position to change the component, there is plenty of options to validate the async data.

- [react-form-input-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-input-validation) - A customized npm package to validate the react form validations including async validation option.

Reference - [`registerAsync`](https://gokulakannant.github.io/react-form-input-validation/classes/reactforminputvalidation.html#registerasync) validation rule

Please check my [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-form-validation-kqs6f) for the React Material UI example.

Comment: I don't want to have to change my component or use more libraries, in your example you put if (username === "foo") in my case I want to know if that value exists in my database

Comment: Yes. I am checking the foo username in setTimeout. Instead, you can do your API call and check the username existence in the success callback of the API call.